# Map field of first file based on patten matching in second file

Tags: shell-script, awk, command-line, pattern-matching

I have two tab-delimited files where I need to match text in the first column of file 1 to *any* position in lines of file 2. Upon a match I then want to print what's in the second column of the matching line of file 1 to the end of the matching line in file 2 (example below).

I know this can almost certainly be done with awk, but I'm not very competent in using awk or sed and searching related questions on here and trying to adapt their script hasn't worked out for me. Any input would be much appreciated.

File 1

```
protein_1.p1     note "PJD5F7, match to databaseID=64575, (species X)";
protein_1.p2     note "PJD5F7, match to databaseID=64575, (species X)";
protein_3.p1     note "PA5F9H, match to databaseID=93689, (species W)";
protein_4.p1     note "Q7GT5J, match to databaseID=89045, (species Y)";
protein_4.p3     note "YE6G3L, match to databaseID=44968, (species Z)";
```

File 2

```
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_1.p1"; parent "protein_1";
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_1.p2"; parent "protein_1";
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_2.p1"; parent "protein_2";
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_2.p2"; parent "protein_2";
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_3.p1"; parent "protein_3";
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_4.p1"; parent "protein_4";
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_4.p2"; parent "protein_4";
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_4.p3"; parent "protein_4";
```

Desired output

```
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_1.p1"; parent "protein_1"; note "PJD5F7, match to databaseID=64575, (species X)";
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_1.p2"; parent "protein_1"; note "PJD5F7, match to databaseID=64575, (species X)";
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_2.p1"; parent "protein_2";
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_2.p2"; parent "protein_2";
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_3.p1"; parent "protein_3"; note "PA5F9H, match to databaseID=93689, (species W)";
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_4.p1"; parent "protein_4"; note "Q7GT5J, match to databaseID=89045, (species Y)";
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_4.p2"; parent "protein_4";
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_4.p3"; parent "protein_4"; note "YE6G3L, match to databaseID=44968, (species Z)";
```

Comment: How do you define a match? You say anywhere in file two, but doesn't it need to at least be in a quoted string? Can `protein_3.p1` appear outside quotes in file2 and, if it does, is that a match?

Comment: Yes, an ideal solution would include protein_3.p1 appearing outside of quotes as a positive match.

Comment: And would `thisisnotprotein_3.p1` be considered a match? Or do we need to find it as a "word", so surrounded by spaces or other non-word characters?

Comment: Either you have always only a unique "protein.*' for every row of file2, in a well-defined (fixed or by regexp) position of the last part, but you say "at any position", or your description is not determinative for the output. I mean probably you should slightly modify the description, and then the matching would be faster also.

Comment: I mean file2 cannot have: `chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_1.p1"; parent "protein_2";` right? Because it would have two matches "for any position". So it has a unique match into file1/filed1. Is this always in a specific field of file2? for example the 4th or the last field.

Comment: The match would always be in the last tab delimited field of file 2, but the last field consists of different descriptors with values in quotation marks separated by semicolons. I am actually working with GTF gene annotation file format. There should only be one match per line, but I said "at any position" I guess because I want to be able to do the same thing for a slightly different file format that would have the match in a different place.

Comment: terdon, yes I would like to match it as a word thus excluding matches such as "thisisnotprotein_3.p1" or "protein_3.p1exon1" if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could parse `file1`, map values (`$2`) to keys (`$1`), then parse `file2` and append value to line, when a part of the line (`$3`) matches any key.

```bsh
BEGIN {OFS = FS = "\t"}
FNR == NR {arr[$1] = $2; next}
{for (x in arr) if ($3 ~ x) {$0 = $0 " " arr[x]; break}}
{print}
```

This prints correct results for your example but it is not what you want for many reasons. The first of them is that it could fail for various cases, like `protein_1.p1` and `protein_1.p11`. The second reason is perfomance, the time for every line of file2 is not constant but ~ size of `file1`.

---

So we have to modify the above script. You probably want to define a regex for the protein string to match. This way, the matching becomes strict enough and also at second parse, time depends on matching a regex on a field, not on the array size.

```bsh
BEGIN {OFS = FS = "\t"; re = "\\<protein_[[:digit:]]+.p[[:digit:]]+\\>"}
FNR == NR {if ($1 ~ re) arr[$1] = $2; next}
match($3, re) {$0 = $0 " " arr[substr($3,RSTART,RLENGTH)]}
{print}
```

Notes:

- `re`: "protein_" followed by one or more digits, ".p" and again one or more digits All this inside word bountaries. The dot is literal. Word characters are `[:alnum:]` and `_` so the rest are bountaries.
- Also there is a sanity check for the 1st field of `file1`.
- If a `match()` is found, then built-in variables `RSTART`, `RLENGTH` hold the index and the length of the matched string, and this substring is what we use into the hash.

Usage:

```
> awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_1.p1"; parent "protein_1"; note "PJD5F7, match to databaseID=64575, (species X)";
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_1.p2"; parent "protein_1"; note "PJD5F7, match to databaseID=64575, (species X)";
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_2.p1"; parent "protein_2"; 
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_2.p2"; parent "protein_2"; 
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_3.p1"; parent "protein_3"; note "PA5F9H, match to databaseID=93689, (species W)";
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_4.p1"; parent "protein_4"; note "Q7GT5J, match to databaseID=89045, (species Y)";
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_4.p2"; parent "protein_4"; 
chromosome_1    programID   transcript_id "protein_4.p3"; parent "protein_4"; note "YE6G3L, match to databaseID=44968, (species Z)";
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly and is flexible enough for all the files I need to modify.

Comment: Very well, also without knowing much details on your domain, I think that matching a regexp here makes it customizable for small changes, similar searches.